# How to debug Solid Start server side functions

Tags: solid-js, solid-start

How do I go about Node --inspect Debbuging Solid Start server-side functions? I don't know what entry to use or the correct settings.

It's hard to use the console log all the time.

Typically I want to debug things like `createServerAction$`

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a debugger first, like any other NodeJS application then use `debugger` or other debugging keywords:

How to attach a debugger varies, say you are using VSCode editor, the simplest way would be:

1. Open the terminal window.
2. Create a Debug Terminal by pressing `+⌄` icon and selecting Javascript Debug Terminal.
3. Start your application like you normally do. For solid start templates, it is `npm run dev`.
4. Locate the code you want to debug and type `debugger`.
5. Refresh your window if the code snippet is already executed when you add the debugger keyword.

There are alternative ways to add which you an read about it here:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging
- https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/